# Event Handler With Custom Parameters Not Removing

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

I am adding a custom event to a DataGridView to handle cell clicks. This 
needs a parameter passed to it.

I first attempt to delete the previous event handler, as I am sending the same DataGridView in and populating it each time.

```
//To delete the old handle
        DataGridViewToPopulate.CellClick -= (sender, e) => DataGridView_CellClick(sender, e, SourceObject);    
//To add new handle
        DataGridViewToPopulate.CellClick += (sender, e) => DataGridView_CellClick(sender, e, SourceObject);
```

My problem is, when this runs the second time, and the SourceObject has changed, the event still has the original SourceObject being sent to it (I believe the original handle is never removed).

I need to dynamically remove all CellClick events (or even all, there aren't that many).

Comment: You cannot unsubscribe an event handler that's written as a lambda.  That requires an exact match with the target object and method, but these are distinct methods.  You must use a plain private method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "this", when you are calling the second time the -= operator, is a different object than the first time you executed the +=. So that -= will not detach that first object, and you would be attaching a second object while not removing the first one.

If that's the case, you should try to find the way to detach that first object.

Comment: I 100% realize that is the issue.

I don't know how to remove the previous event without having that object (I don't at that time).

Comment: Why don't you use a method group instead of a lambda? So create a separate method `private void OnDataGridCellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) { /* do whatever and you can reference SourceObject if it's an instance member */ }` and you can do `DataGridViewToPopulate.CellClick -= OnDataGridCellClick;` and `DataGridViewToPopulate.CellClick  += OnDataGridCellClick;`

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi This is inside of a static class. I don't have access to the object outside of what I pass in. I also no longer have access to the previous object(s) that have been referenced.

Comment: But that first object goes out of scope at some time, right? could you detach it from the event just before going out of scope?

Comment: @JorgeY. Not easily. The DataGridView is a mimic of the object to allow for manual population. The work is happening inside the objects themselves, but I am just passing in the same DataGridView each time. I had attempted to start with a new DataGridView every time, but that always displays an empty DataGridView when I try to use it, and have no clue why, so I'm passing it in instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution with reflection,

```
        private static void UnsubscribeOne(object target)
    {

        Delegate[] subscribers;
        Type targetType;
        string EventName = "EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWCELLCLICK";

        targetType = target.GetType();

        do
        {
            FieldInfo[] fields = targetType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
            {

                if (field.Name == EventName)
                {

                    EventHandlerList eventHandlers = ((EventHandlerList)(target.GetType().GetProperty("Events", (BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))).GetValue(target, null)));
                    Delegate d = eventHandlers[field.GetValue(target)];

                    if ((!(d == null)))
                    {

                        subscribers = d.GetInvocationList();

                        foreach (Delegate d1 in subscribers)
                        {

                            targetType.GetEvent("CellClick").RemoveEventHandler(target, d1);

                        }

                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            targetType = targetType.BaseType;

        } while (targetType != null);

    }
```